# Connecting Android app to Gmail IMAP using AccountManager

Tags: android, oauth, gmail, imap, accountmanager

I am making an Android app that periodically connects to Gmail and analyzes the users messages for data. I am able to connect to Gmail fine if the user inputs their username and password, but obviously, I want a different solution so I don't store the password on the phone.

I want to use AccountManager but I have encountered a problem. It appears that it is easy to connect to all Google's APIs *except* Gmail. I'm having trouble finding how to use the token that AccountManager provides.

Is it possible to connect to Gmail's IMAP using AccountManager? If so, how?

Comment: I am also looking for similar solution. Did you find any?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have temporarily given up on AccountManager and am just using XOauth. I'll let you know if I find a solution later.